# Create calculated tables in Excel 2016 Data Model

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have multiple tables in Excel 2016 data model. These tables come from data maintained in other excel worksheets and are imported through Excel Query to populate a data model to take advantage of superior data management features that are available (e.g., DAX, date tables, relational joins, etc.)

However, I would like to be able to create "calculated tables" (with DAX expressions) by applying filters, unions, etc. to target and transform the existing data elements. The goal to use the "calculated tables" in the Data Model for pivot tables, etc. Is this possible within Excel 2016? If not, what complementary tools (apart from SQL) are necessary? TIA.

Comment: Be sure to isolate your question to a specific issue.  Questions that are Too Broad can be closed.

Comment: Revised question to be more specific (thanks). Excel data model creates tables that are linked to "source input" from data files, SQL, other data bases, CSVs, Excel tables, etc. The DAX langauge implemented in Excel 2016 purportedly has functions to create "calculated" or "virtual" tables that are generally mashups of existing tables. These calculated tables can then be used for further analysis. My question is can this be done within Excel 2016 or whether I need to use complementary tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

[Here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/transition-matrix-using-calculated-tables/) (Though i note the article is old):

> Unfortunately, calculated tables are not available in Excel 2016. If
>   you need a similar solution with Excel 2016, you can rely on linked
>   back tables (i.e. queries over the data model materialized in Excel
>   tables and then loaded back in the model). The only limitation is that
>   the size of linked back tables cannot exceed the physical limit of 1M
>   rows of Excel, whereas DAX calculated tables have no limit in size and
>   can work in many more scenarios, resulting in a very elegant and neat
>   model.

I think it is for Power BI particularly using the "New Table" feature and SSAS tabular using new calculated table:

[Uses for the New Table Feature in Power BI](https://powerpivotpro.com/2017/02/uses-for-new-table-feature-power-bi/))

> This is only available in Power BI Desktop and not in any of the Excel
>   versions or SSAS Tabular.  This feature is essentially a “Calculated
>   Table” function.  You can pass any valid DAX measure that returns a
>   table of values, and the table will be materialised and loaded into
>   the data model.

And with SSAS [calculated table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/create-a-calculated-table-ssas-tabular).

> How to create a calculated table
>
> First, verify the tabular model has a compatibility level of 1200 or
>   higher. You can check the Compatibility Level property on the model in
>   SSDT.
>
> Switch to the Data View. You can't create a calculated table in
>   Diagram View.
>
> Select Table > New calculated table.
>
> Type or paste a DAX expression (see below for some ideas).
>
> Name the table.
>
> Create relationships to other tables in the model. See Create a
>   Relationship Between Two Tables (SSAS Tabular) if you need help with
>   this step.
>
> Reference the table in calculations or expressions in your model or
>   use Analyze in Excel for ad hoc data exploration.

Comment: Thanks! I've marked as good solution, but as I'm a noob, my response needs to be vetted. I've been able to load my Excel 2016 data model (via import) into Power BI Desktop. Shame that one can't do this through Excel 2016 directly. Again, thank you for the excellent solution.

Comment: i think you can still accept as answer (check box in the upper left). Did you mean you tried to upvote?

Comment: Yes, was trying to “up vote”. Found the “check box” - though mind you it’s really only a “check” without the box. Oh the woes of modern user interface! Cheers.

Comment: Looking for a way to easily manipulate/transform vectors/arrays of budget information. Example: from 12000 elements find those that match XYZ and reduce amount by 5%. Looking for business analyst rather than programmer solution. Know of anything?

Comment: Post as a new question? You could use Python or R easily for this.

Answer (score 3):

As of now (August 2019), Excel does *not* support generation of calculated tables using DAX. I personally believe Microsoft should consider this, given that DAX is efficient in data aggregation and analysis.

**Get and Transform**

Until having the feature implemented by Microsoft, there is a good alternative within Excel (*versions from 2010 onward*) by utilizing *Get and Transform* (called also *PowerQuery* in older versions).

Using this tool, you will be able to load the same data set (table or other data source) and transform it as a separate table into the data model.

**Advantages:**

- It is powerful in terms of source data conversion, which extends beyond simple filtering and can deal with importing raw data extracts.

I personally used this approach, and has saved me tremendous time.

**Disadvantage:**

- Get and Transform is a slower and indirect solution compared to DAX.
- You need to refresh the query sources, whenever there is change of the source data.

**Where is it located**

- In Excel 2016, to Get and Transform Tool is available Data/New Query.

Please let me know if you need any further explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to add DAX tables to data model in Excel.

[image]

- Use Existing Connection to get whatever table to Excel sheet.

[image]

Right click on a table and select Edit DAX. Then shape your DAX code after EVALUATE command.

[image]

Add this new DAX shaped table from Excel sheet to your data model.