# Is it possible to convert DAX functions into a Measure so I can filter with a slicer?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, slicers

I'm just getting my feet wet with DAX and the like, and I know the solution I'm looking for is probably very simple and elegent, but it's at the very edge of my knowledge.

I really hope you can help me out :)

The data I'm working with is a large list of claims.

The data gives a `Timestamp` when a `'Claim ID'` is `'Ready for Review'` and `'Complete'`

Because the nature of the business, sometimes a claim goes back into `'Ready for Review'` after it's been 'Complete'ed, so some `'Claim ID'`s can have multiple lines that are marked `'Ready for Review'`.

Right now I have three DAX functions to calculate if a claim is currently `'Ready for Review'`

> Columns and such:
>
> `RFE State History` is the table
>
> `Timestamp` gives the date and time down to the second
>
> `Claim Id` is the claim number
>
> `Status Label` will either be "Ready for Review" or "Complete"

```
MaxDate: =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'RFE State History'[Timestamp] ),
    FILTER (
        'RFE State History',
        'RFE State History'[Claim Id] = EARLIER ( 'RFE State History'[Claim Id] )
    )
)
```

This filters by claim number, then outputs the latest date of the lot.

```
IsLatest: =
IF('RFE State History'[Timestamp]='RFE State History'[MaxDate],"Latest")
```

When the `MaxDate` value equals the date on this line, output "Latest"

```
Ready for Review: =
IF (
    'RFE State History'[Status Label] = "Ready for Review"
        && 'RFE State History'[IsLatest] = "Latest",
    1
)
```

When the column `IsLatest` is "Latest", output "1"

---

I then use 'Redy for Review' in a Pivot Table to sum up how many claims are `Ready to Review` at that particular moment.

What I need to do from here:

I want to be able to use a Slicer to tell how many claims were `Ready to Reiew` on any particular day in the past (and seperately: in each hour of the day as well so we can track progress throughout the day).

After Googling about for a couple weeks I ran across these:

~[Is it possible to use a slicer as a parameter to a DAX Summarize function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015485/is-it-possible-to-use-a-slicer-as-a-parameter-to-a-dax-summarize-function)

~[DAX Fridays! #93: MAXX | Fill down with DAX and Power Query (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQIDJVkFW8o)

~[This blog entry on SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](http://umashanthan.blogspot.com/2017/04/how-to-use-summarizecolumns-function.html)

~[This PowerBI Post on SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-use-Summarizecolumns-to-filter-by-Year-and-Description/td-p/133177)

Which leads me to believe I need to write a Measure that basically does the three DAX functions (`MaxDate`, `IsLatest`, and `Ready for Review`) all at the same time using FILTER and SUMMARIZECOLUMNS so they can be filtered with a Slicer.

Like I said up top there: I'm pretty sure the solution is really simple; I've tried my hand at adapting them to a Measure with no luck. I am only really starting in the DAX world, so I know there's a lot I don't know and don't have a proper grasp on quite yet.

I am really hoping you can help me out here by pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to count the number of Ready for Review claims at a given day or hour you selected with a slicer?

If that is the case  you can can:

1. Create a new calculated table with the following code. You can find it right next to the button for a calculated column in the modelling menu

   ```
   DateTime = 
   ADDCOLUMNS (
       CROSSJOIN (
           CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2000, 1, 1 ), DATE ( 2025, 12, 31 ) ),
           UNION (
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 1, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 2, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 3, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 4, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 5, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 6, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 7, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 9, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 10, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 11, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 12, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 13, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 14, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 15, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 16, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 17, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 18, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 19, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 20, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 21, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 22, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 23, 0, 0 ) ),
               ROW ( "Time", TIME ( 24, 0, 0 ) )
           )
       ),
       "DateTime", [Date] + [Time],
       "Hour", HOUR ( [Time] )
   )
   ```

Thanks for the answer in this post: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/how-to-build-a-calendar-table-with-date-and-time/td-p/241728

2. Create a measure for you previous calculations

   ```
   Ready for Review = 
   var _selectedPeriod = MAX ( DateTime[DateTime] ) // Grab DateTime from the selected value in DateTime. This can be a single value or the end of a period. Default is last available date in DateTime
   RETURN
       COUNTX (
           'RFE State History' ,
           var _maxDate =
               CALCULATE(
                   MAX ( 'RFE State History'[Timestamp] ) ,
                   ALL ( 'RFE State History' ) , 
                   'RFE State History'[Claim Id] = EARLIER( 'RFE State History'[Claim Id] ) ,
                   'RFE State History'[Timestamp] <= _selectedPeriod             
               )

           var _isLast = 
               _maxDate = 'RFE State History'[Timestamp]

           RETURN
               IF( AND ( _isLast = TRUE() , 'RFE State History'[Status Label] = "Ready for Review" ) , 1 )
       )
   ```
3. Create a slicer using DateTime from your calendar table and have a visual with the above produced measure

Comment: Awesome :D I'm having trouble with Step 1 haha. I think I'm clueless where to put the code to generate the calendar: I've put it in a blank query, but nothing happens; I put that blank query into Power Pivot Editor and try putting the code into a blank cell and get the error: "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value." I've tried putting it in the Advanced Editor (thinking: maybe this is some M code), still no-go. I'm still trying things, but I feel I am missing something obvious here haha

Comment: I'll edit my post so it is more detailed, give me a sec.

Comment: Aha! That makes more sense. Apparently Calculated Tables were taken out of Excel 2016 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848240/create-calculated-tables-in-excel-2016-data-model). In the Power Pivot editor there's a button that makes a new Date Table that's super handy, though it doesn't do the hours. I'll figure out a solution eventually to this (even if I have to manually build one myself!)

Comment: Maybe try importing a custom made excel table from another source. You could also try the free PowerBI desktop, this will also allow you to visualize your Ready for Review count over time in a bar chart.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about you :) I've manually made a table with hours and am trying to make the Datamodel work with it right now. (DateTime isn't hooked up correctly or such).  It looks like your code is bringing through the total numbers, so I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you so much for your help! (And I'll comment again when I get it working)